# What is wrong with my delete function for Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a BST and I want to add/delete/find/inorder_traversal/... on it. But when I want to delete an item, there is a problem.

initialize tree:

```
node_t *init() {
    node_t *node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->data = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

`add()` function:

```
int add(node_t *node, void *data) {
    if (node->data == NULL) { //first time when there is only root node exists
        node->data = data;
        printf("%d -> %p\n", (int)node->data, node);
        return 0;
    }
    node_t *prev = NULL, *ptr;
    ptr = node;
    char type;
    while (ptr) {
        prev = ptr;
        if (data < ptr->data) {
            ptr = ptr->left;
            type = 'l';
        } else
        if (data > ptr->data) {
            ptr = ptr->right;
            type = 'r';
        }
    }
    if (type == 'l') {
        node_t *node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        prev->left = node;
        printf("%d -> %p\n", (int)node->data, node);
        return 1;
    } else
    if (type == 'r') {
        node_t *node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        prev->right = node;
        printf("%d -> %p\n", (int)node->data, node);
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`del()` function:

```
int del(node_t *node, void *data) {
    if (data < node->data) {
        del(node->left, data);
    } else
    if (data > node->data) {
        del(node->right, data);
    } else
    if (data == node->data) {
        if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) {  // leaf node
            free(node);
            return 0;
        } else
        if (node->left != NULL) {       //node has only left child
            node->data = node->left->data;
            node->left->data = 0;
            free(node->left);
            return 0;
        } else
        if (node->right != NULL) { //node has only right child
            node->data = node->right->data;
            node->right->data = 0;
            free(node->right);
            return 0;
        } else
        if (node->left != NULL && node->right != NULL) { // node has two children
            node_t *temp = min_value(node->right);
            node->data = temp->data;
            del(node->right, data);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`main()`:

```
int main() {
    node_t *tree;
    tree = init();
    add(tree, (void*)40);
    add(tree, (void*)10);
    add(tree, (void*)30);
    add(tree, (void*)25);
    add(tree, (void*)50);
    add(tree, (void*)11);
    add(tree, (void*)76);

    preorder_traversal(tree);
    printf("\n");
    del(tree, (void*)30);
    preorder_traversal(tree);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

before deleting, I run `inorder_traversal()`, then delete number 30, and again run `inorder_traversal()`, but the output is as below:

```
40 10 11 25 30 50 76
40 10 11 0 25 50 76
```

Guys I would appreciate if you help me.

Also, `min_value()` function is as below:

```
node_t *min_value(node_t *node) {
    while (node->left != NULL) {
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Good to add `min_value()` code in the post

Comment: Are you sure *data* is present in your tree ? If not you have to check *node* is not NULL at the beginning because the two first cases can reach the end of a branch.  Why *else if (data == node->data){* rather than *else* when you know it is not < nor > ? Same thing for *else if(node->left != NULL && node->right != NULL){* when you know both are not NULL because of tests before

Comment: So according to your assumption, You're saying that my add() function might have insertion problem ?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Added to the question sir

Comment: @bruno done sir.

Answer (score 2):

When you *free* nodes in *del* you let them in the tree so later when you access them in *preorder_traversal* or a new call of *del* etc you have an undefined behavior.

When you free a node you have to remove it from the tree.

You also suppose the data to remove is present in the tree, if this is not the case the two first cases will reach the end of a branch and you will dereference NULL with bad consequences. You need first to check if *node* is NULL to return

Also in

> ```
>    else if(node->left != NULL){       //node has only left child
> ```

you do not know if *node->right* is NULL or not, your assumption *node has only left child* is false

In *init* you set a first node without data, that has no sense.

I encourage you to modify your add/del function to get a *node *** rather than a *node* allowing you to modify the tree/variable memorizing the root